# How to use Cavalieri's Principle in conjunction with the area of a horizontal cross section?

Tags: calculus, volume

I have a three-dimensional solid defined with respect to an orthonormal frame $Oxyz$ by

$$3 z^2 < ax + by  < z$$

I would like to find its volume  using Cavalieri's principle where the horizontal cross sections are normal to $z$ axis.

The integration tool I would like to use is one dimensional integration rather than double integrals.

Is there a numerical answer to this problem 3?

What is  the differential volume that gets multiplied by $dx$ or $dz$?

There could be a number of ways to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: numerical solution?

Comment: @Narasimham, What do you mean by numerical solution? Could I integrate by the z axis?

Comment: seems that you are confusing up some different concepts

Comment: Do you agree with the new presentation I have given to your question ?

Comment: Cavalieri's principle is interesting only if the areas of the cross sections are easy to compute. What is their shapes in this case ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, The shape of the cross section is the shaded area between two lines with -1 slope and c and c * pow(4.0) x intercepts and y intercepts.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<c<{1\over3}$ then $3c^2<c$. It follows that for such a $c$ the plane $z=c$ intersects your solid in the infinite parallel strip
$$3c^2<ax+by<c\tag{1}$$
of positive width, hence infinite area. Using Cavalieri's principle (or Fubini's theorem) it follows that this solid has infinite volume.

Concerning volumes of bodies as integrals: If you are given a finite "body" $B\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ you can project it to the $z$-axis and obtain an interval $[p,q]$, and you can intersect it with planes $z={\rm const.}$ and obtain plane slices
$$B_z:=\{(x,y)\>|\>(x,y,z)\in B\}$$
of area ${\rm area}(B_z)\geq 0$. Now by Fubini's theorem one has
$${\rm vol}(B)=\int_B 1\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)=\int_p^q\int_{B_z}1\> {\rm d}(x,y)\>dz=\int_p^q {\rm area}(B_z)\>dz\ .$$
In the case at hand $B_z$ is empty unless $3z^2<z$, and this is the case iff $0<z<{1\over3}$. We therefore have $p=0$, $q={1\over3}$. But ${\rm area}(B_z)=\infty$ $(p<z<q)$, since $(1)$ defines an infinite parallel strip of positive width, whatever $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$ for these $z$. It follows that ${\rm vol}(B)=\infty$ not only per inspection, but also per integral.

Comment: Your answer is what I was hoping to see. Could I ask what was your integral and the limits of  integration? Thank you.

Comment: Blattter, Suppose a = 1 and b = -1 , would we still have infinite area? How would I calculate area as a function of z where a = 1 and b = -1? Why is p = 0 and q = 1/3? Thank you.

Comment: Suppose a = 1 and b = -1 , would we still have infinite area? How would I calculate area as a function of z where a = 1 and b = -1? Why is p = 0 and q = 1/3? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Given that you are still trying to understand Cavalieri's principle and all that it is not very helpful to provide a degenerate example as working piece.

Comment: Why is this a degenerate case? Thank you.

Comment: Given that a = 1 and b = -1, what is the definite integral answer? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: If $a=1$ and $b=-1$ consider as  an example   the set $$B_{1/6}=\left\{(x,y)\>\biggm|\>{1\over12}<x-y<{1\over6}\right\}$$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, which is definitely an infinite strip.  The final answer $\infty$ obtained without really working makes the chosen example "degenerate". – That's my last word in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Monge form of surface and using Green's theorem find area enclosed from  closed curve boundary. Then integrate functionally with respect to  z.

EDIT1:

Monge form is like

$$ z= f(x,y) $$

e.g., like

$$ z= (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2  $$

Rather than repeat it, referring to anonymous's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19269/applying-greens-theorem) among others in a particular example to compute cross-section $A$ of an ellipse using line integral. A suitable $single $ parameter is needed to link $(x,y)$.

$$ A =\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{\partial{D}} xdy - ydx = ... $$

and then the usual

$$  V = \int A\cdot dz $$

Suggested this as you wanted a separate evalution for each level cross-section.

An added advantage is the possibility of using any curvilinear coordintes, not just Cartesian, here we are using variables $(x,y)$ in place of more general curvilinear  parameters $(u,v). $

Comment: I think your answer is great. Please show us how you used Green's theorem and integrated with respect to z. What is the Monge form of surface ? Thank you.